# Do portraits of wizards only have their characters or also their memories?

Tags: harry-potter

Do the magical portraits, like the ones of the headmasters of Hogwarts, still have all their memories?

Hypothetical example: If Harry's parents were on a portrait, would they just love Harry and be good parents for him to have a nice talk with OR would they be able to tell him it wasn't Sirius who betrayed them but Peter Pettigrew?

Comment: The answer on that question should cover your questions. We try not to have duplicate question and answer threads. Don't worry, though: that just means your question has wide appeal!

Comment: Thanks, I looked for it but I couldn't find a duplicate because apparently I misspelled portraits.

Comment: @Adamant There's a whole *pile* of interrelated duplicates for this. Added a few more to the dupe banner.